# Java ArrayList and LinkedList - adding element at end implementation details

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist, linked-list

My understanding of why arraylist is faster than a linkedlist is that with an arraylist you basically only need one action - update the reference at the end array element, whereas with a linked list you have to do much more e.g. create a new node, update 2 references, go through linked list and update the last node to point to the new one etc.

However I am not sure how java implement these. How does the arraylist know where the "last" element is, does it store a value of the last element or does it traverse the array and add a new element after the last?

And linked lists, do they store a reference to the last node in the list, or do they traverse the entire list to get to the end?

Comment: The JDK comes with the sources. Read them, and you'll find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source:

[ArrayList](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html):

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

[LinkedList](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html):

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
    return true;
}

void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An array-list is only faster at certain operations. If you add an element in the middle of an array the arraylist needs to copy basically all data into a new array. It is only if the arraylist already have allocated room for new data it is fast when inserting data where it is empty (usually in the end). Read/update by index is very-fast.

A LinkedList is fast when inserting since it never require the whole array to be copied. But accessing data in a linked list is slow since you need to "walk" all the elements until you are at the element you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the sources of `java.*` classes.

However, answering particular your question: there is `int` field in `ArrayList` class, which contains current size of filled internal array area. When you add new value in `ArrayList` object, this field increments and then directly addresses to that element in internal array.