# Which is faster - inserting an element at the end of an array or a linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

Which is faster - inserting an element at the end of an array or a linkedlist ?

Comment: By array do you mean ArrayList or an actual Array? Because adding to any point in an array is the same speed but it can't get longer

Comment: The key things here: **subtle** details matter. So be might want to update your question to be really precise. And you want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Performance on Java ArrayList vs LinkedList, pertaining to only Creation/Insertion and sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29584600/642706), [Java ArrayList and LinkedList - adding element at end implementation details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14496638/642706), [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/642706), [ArrayList vs LinkedList Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24963620/642706), [java linkedlist slower than arraylist when adding elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5346039/642706).

Answer (score 10):

I assume you meant [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) when you said "array", since in Java you can't "add" to a full array.

Firstly if you're "inserting at the end" you're actually *appending* to the end not, "inserting". This distinction is important because *inserting* into an ArrayList at an arbitrary position is an O(n) operation, because all elements to the right must be "shifted" along by one position to make room for the element being inserted.

Adding to (the tail of) a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is always a O(1) (constant time) operation.

Adding to an ArrayList is usually a O(1) operation, but *may* be a O(n) operation if the backing array is full, because a new array must be allocated and every element copied across. In the general case of the array not being full, the performance of ArrayList is (slightly) faster than LinkedList, but the difference is very small.

The amortised cost of both is the same, but if constant time is required every time, only a LinkedList can do it.

Comment: And to answer what was asked, adding to the "end" of an array will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is `>=` the array length or `<0`, O(1) otherwise.

Comment: *"I assume you meant ArrayList when you said "array", since in Java you can't "add" to a full array."* Who said it was full?

Answer (score 1):

Appending an element to the end of `Array` would be faster then Adding to a `LinkedList` as adding to a `LinkedList` always means creation of a cell at the end of the list and then adding a value to it. In Array you just add a value to existing cell. However, in `Array` if it is already full and doesn't have a space you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while in the `LinkedList` you will never have this problem as the List will always grow according to your needs. Also there is distinct difference between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` with `ArrayList` there is a random access which means the access to any element is always O(1) while in `LinkedList`it is always sequential access which means that access time will differ depending on the index and in worst case scenario is O(n). However, Appending to `LinkedList` is Always O(1) but not so in `ArrayList` With ArrayList if it is not full it will be O(1) but if it is full it will first grow by more then one cell and only ten it will add the value, so the worst case scenario is O(n)